# Developer Tools: Instruments command line interface

Tags: iphone, automation, instruments

Do you know if it is possible to launch or attach UIAutomation tool to a process on the actual iOS device using Instruments command line interface ?

I know that there is command line interface for instruments but so far I haven't been able to connect to the device.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a bug in the command line Instruments interface. It's documented here:

http://openradar.appspot.com/9150033

I filed a bug through my job, and they closed it as a dupe of this one.

When it is fixed, it should work like the following:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html

The workarounds would all be hacky, the Instruments product lacks osascript extensions as well. I'm going to be investigating hacks, while waiting for this fix to come through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -w switch along with your device UDID